# Proofs without words of some well-known historical values of $\pi$?

Tags: geometry, circles, math-history, pi, visualization

Two of the earliest known documented approximations of the value of $\pi$ are $\pi_B=\frac{25}{8}=3.125$ and $\pi_E=\left(\frac{16}{9}\right)^2$, from Babylonian and Egyptian sources respectively. I've read that the Egyptian figure at least could be justified through some geometrical diagram which made the approximation a visually obvious statement about the areas of circles and squares. As far as I know, the Babylonian value on the other hand could have simply been obtained empirically through direct measurement of circle diameters and circumferences; I really have no idea. My question is simply can anyone provide simple visual proofs of these approximations? It doesn't matter to me if the proofs happen to be the historically used ones or not, as long as they get the job done.

Side-note: The Egyptian value pertains to the area-$\pi$, whereas the Babylonian one is about the circumference-$\pi$. As far as anyone knew back in the day, the two constants were not necessarily equal *a priori*. Bonus points go to answers that can demonstrate both approximations for both pi's.

Comment: Take a peek here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/activity/pi-approximation.html

Comment: "Bonus points"? Are you a magician?

Comment: I'd prefer the word 'approximations' rather than 'values' in the title.

Answer (score 7):

Here we have a visual proof of the egyptian $\pi$:

[image]

And here one of the babylonian $\pi$:
[image]

Comment: Can this be generalized to a $n$-gon?

Comment: Generalize? This is not an 25-gon, although it comes close. You can pick your n value for an actual closed up n-gon, but it won't (ever?) correspond to a "nice" value like r/4. If you use "nice" values, you (always?) won't close the polygon. We can calculate the perimeter of an n-gon but generally will depend on sin values (which are generally not "nice" nor rational). [a regular 25-gon has perimeter 25sin(pi/25)]

Comment: These are all eyeball measurements. They look good if you use good tools and have a good eyeball. [lol]. It's probably true that these approximations were engineering numbers and not theoretical mathematics in play.

Comment: Pick any "nice" value like say r/5. Then find the multiple of that that is closest to 2pi*r. If it's "close enough" you now have a new engineering approx. If not, repeat using another "nice" fraction. With modern tools, including computer to test at high speed, you can get arbitrarily close although the fractional components will get larger and larger. With primitive tools, you have to use mechanical precision, good eyeballs, and patience.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is historical, but the 25/8 seems pretty natural to me.
The $6\times 6 + 2\times (4 +3) =50$ little squares looks as a decent approximation (the defects compensating the excesses); hence $\pi \approx 50 \times 4/8^2 = 25/8$.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Straight edge and compass construction of a quadrature of a circle is possible only with Babylonian value of pi. Try this link : https://www.academia.edu/8084209/Ancient_Values_of_Pi. Though, Egyptian value of Pi (22/7 or 256/81) is rational, compass and straight edge construction of a quadrature of a circle is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by *only*? There are lots of rational approximations to $\pi$ and they are all constructible.

Comment: Will be pleased to know the other approximate rational value of pi which is constructable with compass and straight edge.

Comment: *Every* rational number is constructible with a compass and straight edge.

Comment: Please construct and show a quadrature of a circle for 256/81 Pi value.